# Angular Button tooltop is behind modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, popper.js

I use Angular 13 with Bootstrap 5.0 and [Mdb](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/).

The modal I created with the help of Mdb seems to be in front of the tooltip of buttons inside the modal, so they wont get displayed properly as you can see in this image:

[image: Tooltip behind Modal]

My Button looks like this:

```
<button (click)="refreshImageSelected()"
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          placement="top"
          tooltip="testesttesttesttesttesttest"
          type="button">
    <i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i>
  </button>
```

So what I tried was changing the z-index of the buttons and the modal which didn't help. I also tried using the bootstrap tooltip with popper.js like in this [tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/) which did work, but they sadly look really different from all the other tooltips and not like they normally should look (like in the bootstrap docs).
I have also tried the tooltips of Mdb but they didn't even appear.

Is there a way to change the z-index of the tooltip property of the buttons seperately?

Edit:
Also tried [Bootstraps tooltip-test class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#tooltips-and-popovers) but it looks like this:

[image: Style is different]

instead of like how it should look:

[image: Correct Tooltip Style]

Comment: I think this is a problem related to the z-index of the tooltip. Now that you are using bootstrap, i suggest to use their [z-index variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/z-index/) so that you have a consistency.

Comment: Yeah I have found that too, but isn't bootstrap automatically using them? Then Tooltip already has the highest value.

Comment: When you use matTooltip then I think the z-index of bootstrap wont be applied to it and instead the z-index of angular material is used. Therefore, the z-index of matTooltip is interfering with the z-index of the modal from bootstrap. I think you should manually apply the bootstrap z-index to the matTooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign z-index of the tooltip to greater than the modal z-index.

`.tooltip { z-index:100000000; }`

Example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Ljtmm/)

Comment: Well it does work even without changing the z-index but the styling of those tooltips is wrong. I edited my question which shows the wrong styling.